# How to insert a Web Banner advertisement that is a index.html file into a anchor tag?

Tags: html, svg, ads

Hi I am new to working with SVG's and animated ads. I have a folder which has a bunch of SVG images and a index.html file that runs the animated banner ad. I need to add the animated banner into a anchor tag or img tag is that possible or is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="htttp://www.somedomain.com" target="_blank"><img src="path to your background image" alt="hero"/></a>
```

Then just drop that into your hero/banner container and adjust the size on the img class as necessary for your design.

Comment: I don't think you understand what I am getting at. The images are just static, the index.html file animates them I need to see the animation in a completely different file and I have to put it into a anchor tag or img tag. Or would it be better to have a gif file?